# jQuery-Validate en petición AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-validate

Quisiera saber cómo realizar lo siguiente, tengo una funcion para poder editar los datos de un formulario, utilizando *CodeIgniter* y *AJAX*, pero quiero validarlo con *jQuery-Validate*. ¿Cómo lo haría antes de la petición? Este es mi codigo, funciona bien:

```html
function edit(id = null) {

    if (!id) {
        alert('error');
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'roles/get_data_id/' + id,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            $("#edit_name").val(response.Name);
            $("#edit_description").val(response.Description);      

            $("#form_edit").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
                var form = $(this); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action') + '/' + id,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response.success === true) {
                            $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');

                            alert('se actualizo');

                            $("#form_edit")[0].reset();
                            table_data.ajax.reload(null, false);  
                        } else {
                            $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');
                            alert('Error al actualizar');
                        }
                    }// /succes
                }); // /ajax
                return false;  
            });       
        }
    });
}
```

... y este es el código que no sé donde agregarlo, son mis reglas de validación.

```html
$('#form_edit').validate({
    highlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahi eliminé la respuesta para que no haya confusión. Espero que des con la solución a tu problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Cuando añades las reglas de validación de los campos y defines como va a actuar mediante errorPlacement puedes colocar el código al principio de las etiquetas de script, pero para realizar la validación de tu formulario, lo debes hacer con el metodo:

```
if ($("#form_edit").valid()) {
//llamada a AJAX si el formulario es valido
}
```

Comment: no comprendo muy bien donde quedarian mis reglas de validacion

Comment: Tus reglas de validacion querdarían al principio de la etiqueta <script> y el código que yo he mandado o bien antes de $("#form_edit").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() { o antes de  $.ajax({

Answer (score 0):

Quedaría algo así :

```
// La variable validación tomar la respues del plugin
   var validacion = $('#form_edit').validate({
        highlight: function (input) {
            $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (input) {
            $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
        }
    });

    if(validacion){
       // tu codigo ajax
    }
```

No estoy asociado al plugin validate, pero si este no retorna la respuesta, debe manejarse con una función callback o una promesa tipo el ".done" de ajax.